# 10.1 printing outside margin

Tags: printing, arcgis-10.1

I have seen on several maps in the case where a polygon overlaps (or maybe underlaps) the data frame, which is distributed to the margins, and text is turned on, that the text can print outside the data frame in the margin area.

It shows this on both the pdf export and the print straight to a plotter.
Has anyone seen this same behavior?
[image: margin printing]

Comment: Am assuming that the thick black line is the outline of the data frame and that the numbers are from a text attribute via labelling.  Do the numbers on the outside of the data frame show up in Layout View or only when you print/export?

Comment: yes and yes, I will have to go back to it to remember. I started noticing it on the plot then noticed it on the pdf. Then plotted directly from both pdf and the mxd and it was there. Can't remember though is I could see it in layout.

Comment: and confound! since I'm not in crunch mode it isn't doing it anywhere now. :(

Comment: oh yeah - I did install terrago. maybe that changed/fixed it?